# Execute jar and display text in jenkins console log

Tags: powershell, batch-file, jenkins, parallel-processing, psexec

I have `abc.jar` file to deploy and run in remote machine.
I have transferred the file using jenkins, now what I have done is, call a `a.bat` batch file on remote machine using `psexec` in `Execute Windows Batch Command`.
`a.bat` executes the `abc.jar` 
When the jar begins execution, the command prompt texts are stored in  a file.
using `java -jar abc.jar >> a.log 2>&1`
Now what I want is to display the `a.log` contents in the jenkins console when the jar file is being executed 
(the file is continuously being written and I want to show it in jenkins console as it is being written)

I have tried to do it using parallel processing by calling `start` twice, one for calling batch file, another using `type` for displaying.

But when I use `start` I get `Process leaked file descriptor` .
Is there any other way I can achieve this. Be it calling powershell  or scheduled task in jenkins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look for tee equivalents in windows , there are few like [GNU utilities for Win32](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/), however if you have cygwin you can still use tee which will easy the prcoess.

Now the wuestion arises how to run my jar file on cygwin from jenkins ?

you can still use execute windows[batch] shell. and add cygwin installation path to the PATH variable and start using linux command like a BOSS.

or you can use powershell tee in built command from batch.

Comment: without setting up cygwin I am able to run `tee` in Windows Powershell. Now need to convert all batch syntaxes to powershell. Thanks for the solution.  Will get back if I need any help. 
P.S.~ we both are from same city ;)